# Best long term storage solution?

Tags: storage, usb-storage, optical-drive, time-capsule, nfc

What's the best device I can store data on for an extremely long time hundreds or thousands of years? Only planning on writing the data on to it once as it's going to be a time capsule kinda basically wanting this to be my last gift to someone... 
So it would need to last underground for that time.

Are there any products that can last or formats like a ssd, flash, nand-chips, nfc magnetic tape, hdd or optical storage?

Comment: This really doesn't seem too broad to me.  I mean, yes, exact storage conditions aren't listed, but the question is pretty clear about what is wanted (suggestions for long-term archival storage lasting multiple centuries).

Comment: even if you could store data for 1000 years, no one in the future would be able to read it easily.  Even if they could read it, that doesnt mean they would understand it in its digital form.

Comment: Cave paintings.

Answer (score 0):

The only long-term archiving technology I know of is [M-Disc optical media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-DISC),
that can keep your data [good for a thousand years](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2933478/storage/m-disc-optical-media-reviewed-your-data-good-for-a-thousand-years.html).

For example, on Amazon [1000 Years Archival Verbatim M-Disc BDXL 100GB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011PZAHTM)
is currently $73.98, for a total of 500 GB.
You will also need the right BD-R burner.

As you know best your own needs, study the technology
to see if it fulfills your requirement.